# Search Button - onSearchRequested() in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, search, software-update

In my activity I have implemented a specific behave when user press Search Button. These suppose implementing

> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean onSearchRequested(){
>         //..............
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

The problem is that, after I have updated my Nexus S to Android 4.1.1 this doesn't work anymore and Search Button starts a Google Web Search instead. That is frustrating! Could these be overwrited to work as before?

Comment: I think this is because starting with Android 4+, it seems that they have renounced to `MeniuButton` and `SearchButton` for `ActionBar`